# Can I mode Firebase DB without using push keys?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I read a tutorial somewhere that says that I should use push keys to come up with a unique push id; is it mandatory? If I have my own unique key then I would rather want to do a set or update not got having to go through the push keys.

Please tell me if I am missing something. Thank you.

Comment: Try this `dataReference().child("your-key-here").setValue( ... );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely NOT mandatory, and not even documented as a "Best Practice" or similar recommendation anywhere. It's simply a useful feature that you can take advantage of if it suits your needs.

You can generate keys any way you want, including client-side, just be prepared to take responsibility for ensuring uniqueness and the consequences related to that need. If you write data to an existing key unexpectedly, Firebase will not stop you - it will silently accept the change as an update request (assuming security rules allow it). The Firebase documents say only this about keys you generate yourself:

> If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/structure-data for more details.

In case you're wondering, one advantage of using Firebase's push-generated keys is that they're generated via a timestamp and are thus sortable. UUIDs and some other key generation techniques are not sortable in this way (unless you take steps to make them so).

Comment: Great answer Chad. We *do* recommend using push IDs for collections that don't have a natural key, because the alternative that most developers otherwise pick is to [use array indices, which are pretty useless when your app scales or is offline](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). But if the items have their own natural key, use that to store them under. For example when storing user records, store them under their UID

Comment: I didn't want to add this to the answer itself because it's for MySQL, but this related article is an interesting read. The lessons about orderable vs. unorderable keys can apply to Firebase even if the MySQL-specific _issue_ doesn't: https://cjsavage.com/guides/mysql/insert-perf-uuid-vs-ordered-uuid-vs-int-pk.html

Comment: Thank you Chad. That answers all I wanted to hear and all that I needed affirmation on.